# How to access $_Get variable in PHP based on another input value

Tags: php, html

I need to access the input value of a dynamic variable based on another input field.

Sample code:

```
$upid=$_GET['upid'];
  $check_box_name='c'.$upid;
  echo $upid;
  $check=$_GET[$check_box_name];
```

any idea how do i access it??...Please help

Comment: What is happening now?

Comment: The code works fine for me... if you browse to `yourpage.php?upid=18&c18=somevalue`, and you then echo `$check`, you'll get `somevalue` as result...

Comment: when i try to echo check it is giving me blank value

Comment: @anandsagar: what URL you have?

Comment: What is your purpose?

Comment: @anandsagar: why do you talk about a `$_GET` variable? I suppose this variable is submitted from a form, am I right? Do you submit this post with `GET` action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you entered should work, but, it is vulnerable to errors, as you are dealing with a user input, you should either do a validation or a failover value.

If you are using PHP5.3+, you can easily do this as follows:

```
if ($check = @$_GET['c' . (@$_GET['upid'])]? : false !== false) {
    //do something with $check
} else {
    //failed
}
```

The `@` sign is used to omit any error or exception from being thrown. Also, it maybe a good thing to escape the `$check` variable for more security.